# Proper names for data - quantile and rank

Tags: descriptive-statistics, terminology, ranks, quantiles

Say I have data from a sample of 100 experiments. For a variable, I'm interested in showing the value `x` with 0.9 probability of non-exceedance, which is equivalent to P90 of the sorted sample.

I'm interested in proper names for these parameters:

`x` is a *percentile*, the 90-percentile to be specific, or more generally speaking, a ***quantile***.

`90` is the *rank* of `x` in my sample. Correct?

What would be the proper name for `0.9`, or `90%`? Also rank? Normalized rank? Strictly speaking it is the *probability of non-exceedance*, but writing that in a table header is not convenient :) A short but correct name for it would be very welcome.

Comment: In ordinary usage 'parameter' refers to a population, not a sample. The word 'statistic' is more commonly used for samples.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it the *level* that is used to calculate the quantiles and percentiles. (I have seen this referred to as a *confidence level*, but I don't like the insinuation that it would mostly be used for [confidence-intervals](/questions/tagged/confidence-intervals).)

(And yes, since you have 100 observations, the rank of the 90% percentile observation is 90. If you had 200 observations, then the 90% percentile observation would have rank 180.)

Comment: I have also seen it as _confidence level_ and I don't like for the same reason you've mentioned. _Level_ somehow has a too strong resemblance to _confidence level_ so not my preferred option. Calling it _rank_ is definitely wrong then. About _normalized rank_? if that makes sense...